# Why is grunt-php router ignoring my base path?

Tags: php, gruntjs

We have one Gruntfile.js that looks like this on my coworker's machine.

```
php: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            port: 8888,
            useAvailablePort: true,
            keepalive: true,
            router: '_router.php',
            base: 'src' //dev mode
        }
    }
},
```

...and it works fine on his machine but not mine. `_router.php` is at the top level directory. Running `grunt dev` leads into no errors in my console during dev deploy.

```
PHP 5.5.27 Development Server started at Wed Sep 23 17:31:54 2015
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8888
Document root is /Users/toszter/Engineering/moo/sources/local/web/src
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
[Wed Sep 23 17:39:33 2015] 127.0.0.1:53910 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF)
```

Yet, I see in my browser at localhost:8888...

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '_router.php' (include_path='.:') in Unknown on line 0
```

Changing the `router` property in the code above to `router: 'src/_router.php'` fixes the problem on my machine, but breaks everyone else.

So it stands needing a bit of explanation: Why do I need to re-specify the base directory explicitly in my `router` property and no one else on my team?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly because `path.resolve` isn't providing absolute paths to the php script spawned in the task by using the simple options given and `options.base` to join the true path to the router.

While the task expects a full path to `router` inside `spawn`, it only gets the relative path from `options.router` inside `php.js`, which pukes rainbow unicorn sparkles everywhere.

The [original issue is here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-php/issues/70). That was eventually [fixed here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-php/commit/5b18aeeb4082c93b5db6fe07c089e7a601b05047), and yet [this problem persisted](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-php/issues/71), so it now [appears fixed here](https://github.com/toszter/grunt-php/commit/6ce0c049f1cb1f3c2a4efdd7ea31deaef1b4fb09) but not yet merged with `grunt-php` master.